# Receiving no response from Salesforce on patch API call

Tags: rest-api, api, patch, response

I am sending a Patch API Request to Salesforce to update one of the accounts in the Org, through postman. the endpoint to which I am sending the request looks like below.

```
https://instanceUrl/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Account/accountId
```

And the request looks like below.

```
{
    "Website" : "www.testcodeinc.com"
}
```

The website value is getting updated to the value that I am sending in the request, but I am not receiving any response from Salesforce at all. Instead, I am receiving the response code of **204**.

To cross verify, I even checked in another API platform named Insomnia by sending the same request, but I am receiving the same response code even there without any response body.

Can someone please let me know if I Should be doing any changes at the salesforce end to receive the response after the update was successful? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A successful update is a 204 response. That status code means "your operation was successful, and there is no response body." If there were an error, you'd get a 4xx or 5xx status code with a response describing the error. If you want a fresh copy of the data, you will need to retrieve it somehow, such as using a GET call, or using a [composite REST resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) to patch and retrieve in one call.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is this normal behavior? Does the Patch API call will never return any response body back to the endpoint, and it's always 204?

Comment: @AkshayVasu Yes, feel free to read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm). *Example response body for updating fields in an Account object /
none returned*

Comment: Sure, Thank you.